# Generated web font doesn't show dots above Ü

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate my font ready for web. I've set the options to include subsetting of the German language.

In the website I put this: `Über WFW Deutschland` but when viewed it comes out as `Uber WFW Deutschland`. Whats weird is that if I view in any IE version it shows correctly. If I switch to any default system font it also displays correctly in any browser.

How can I get my generated font to work correctly?

Update - CSS Code from generator:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PalatinoMedium';
    src: url('../fonts/palatinm-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/palatinm-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/palatinm-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/palatinm-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/palatinm-webfont.svg#PalatinoMedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried different source files for the same font, or are you using just one? Is the page encoding in utf-8? Try to use the html code for the char: &#220

Comment: See update. page is in UTF8. If I use the entity code the `Ü` still appears like `U`

Comment: Make sure o that not only the page encoding is utf-8 but also the encoding of your editor. I tried a quick demo with a ttf file that I found and it worked on Chrome 16, FF 8, all 64 bit on Windows 7. When you say it's working on IE and not on others, it might be related to the file that each browser is using from your collection of source files, try to use just one at the time to evaluate if the problem is from a font file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of fannying about I found that the option `Apply Hinting - Improve Win rendering` when ticked was breaking the font. Un-ticked that and reconverted my font and now the font is displaying as it should.

Although the font doesn't look as nice on Windows...